# Filter distinct queryset by fields of a ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-queryset

*(I think, the title of the question is far from being perfect, which might be the reason why I cannot find any useful help for this. Edits are welcome!)*

Assume the following models:

```py
class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 128)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
```

The next model connects connects `person` and `pizza` and has a an additional boolean field. for the example, let's say the model stores the top pizzas for each person and the boolean field indicates whether the corresponding pizza is among the absolute favorites for the respective person.

```py
class TopPizzasForPerson(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(
        Person,
        related_name = 'top_pizzas',
        on_delete = models.CASCADE
    )
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(
        Pizza, on_delete = models.CASCADE
    )
    is_nearly_perfect = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

The last model stores when a certain person has eaten a certain pizza.

```
class PizzaPersonDateRelation(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(
        Person,
        related_name = 'eaten_pizzas',
        on_delete = models.CASCADE
    )
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza)
    date = models.DateField()
```

I would like to have a list which contains the last date when someone has eaten a specific pizza. So, all combinations of `person` and `pizza` from `PizzaPersonDateRelation` should appear, but in case of multiple occurences of this combination, only the last one should be included. Currently, I do this by:

```py
qs = PizzaPersonDateRelation.objects \ 
    .distinct('person', 'pizza') \ 
    .order_by('person', 'pizza', '-date')
```

My first question now is: How can I limit the above queryset to contain only pizzas which are among the absolute favorites for each person, i.e., where `TopPizzasForPerson.is_nearly_perfect` is `True`?

Here is how I would do it at the python level, not at the database level:

```py
[ 
    data for data in qs \
    if data.person.top_pizzas.filter(pizza = data.pizza, is_nearly_perfect = True).exists()
]
```

The second question is: Can the above queryset be extended to contain additional rows, maybe with `None` for `date` if a pizza which is among the absolute favorites for someone has never ben eaten by that person, i.e., if there is an entry in `TopPizzasForPerson` for a certain `person` and `pizza`, and `is_nearly_perfect` is `True`, but no entry for that combination of `person` and `pizza` exists in `PizzaPersonDateRelation`

Answer (score 0):

This query should get what you are asking.

```
PizzaPersonDateRelation.objects \
.filter(person__top_pizzas__is_nearly_perfect=True) \
.distinct('person', 'pizza') \ 
.order_by('person', 'pizza', '-date')
```

You can use `related_name` to traverse related models.

Comment: This seems not to be what I'm looking for. Let's say, we have `john` and `jimmy` as `person`s, `salami` and `onions` as `pizza`s and `john` has selected `salami` as favorite, and `PizzaPersondateRelation` exists for all four combinations, your suggestion would contain all (distinct) values for `john`. The filter seems to select any person which has any `top_pizza`-relation with `is_nearly_perfect  = True`

Comment: You want to get the all entries where `is_nearly_perfect` is `True` right?

Comment: Well, more or less. I would like to get the latest (`date` in `PizzaPersonDateRelation`) for every (distinct) combination of `person` and `pizza` (in `PizzaPersonDateRelation`) if that combination of `person` and `pizza` has `is_nearly_perfect = True` in `TopPizzasForPerson`.